# Navigation to a route via Hyperlink

Tags: c#, url, routes, navigation

I have a hyperlink in masterpage

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false"  >
    <AnonymousTemplate>
           <%--[ <a href="~/Account/Login"  id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]--%>
           [ <asp:HyperLink ID="LoginHyperLink" NavigateUrl="~/Account/Login" runat="server" >Login</asp:HyperLink> ]
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
         Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName id="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
         [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Account/Login"   /> ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

after clicking on this HyperLink I am expecting a clean URL but I get :

```
http://localhost:25458/Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fLogin
```

and i have defined:

```
Routes.MapPageRoute("Login", "Account/Login", "~/Account/Login.aspx");
```

why is that so ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added  a config file under the account folder 
it seems that it solved the problem for login page but problem still persist with Registration page.

```
<allow users="*" />
```